# Can't make repository by "git init" inspite of showing the message such as "Initialized empty Git repository in ～"

Tags: git, init

I input "git init new" in my commandline.

```
git init new
```

and that commandline shows the message

```
"Initialized empty Git repository in ～"
```

But there is no .git file in the directory

Comment: `cd new` to get to where the repo is.

Comment: Hi!, did you try with just `git init`?

Comment: No, don't do that. You'll place your whole hard drive under Git. You can lose everything if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try a plain `git init` in the dir you want to use

Comment: But not in ~. That would be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helping
I resolved the problem!

Yesterday, I thought that after entering "git init ○○",　".git" file will generate in the directory, and I can see the file.

But this is misunderstanding

Thanks to your comment, I understood

Thank you